# How to add a video in Visual Portfolio?

Tags: wordpress, video, posts, portfolio

I’m quite new to wordpress, currently building a one page website and using Visual Portfolio. I would like to add some videos on my portfolio, so I followed this documentation https://visualportfolio.co/documentation/portfolio-items/video-portfolio-item/.

However I don’t see the video appearing in the portfolio. I tested with 2 videos, portfolio is empty. But I see the video in the video post when I open it (I chose the video url on the video field + I embed the video in the post).

I leads me to 2 questions:

- What did I miss?
- In the documentation, the last line says “Change posts content output template in your theme”, with some code. Where do I find the file to change?

Here is the code the documentation is recommending to add:

```
<?php
$video_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true );

if ( 'video' === get_post_format() && $video_url ) {
    $oembed = wp_oembed_get( $video_url );

    if ( $oembed ) {
        echo $oembed;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you've added, or a screenshot of the settings you're using? Without this info, we can't recreate the problem, or assume to know what's going on.

Comment: Hi @JoelHager, I updated my question with the code I'd like to add (I just don't know where to add it, because this info is not in the documentation). Concerning my settings I don't know what to show you, I'm using wordpress 5.4 and Visual Portfolio 1.16.2. I manage to use Visual Portfolio for my pics, but I don't manage to include videos.

Answer (score 0):

If your video-post open new window, It need add to in  file, what print your single post. For example single.php, single-post.php, singular.php.
You can get all meta key add this code  in this file

```
<?php var_dump(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

I add this code

```
<?php 
$video_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_vp_format_video_url', true );
if ( 'video' === get_post_format() && $video_url ) { 
$oembed = wp_oembed_get($video_url ); 
if ( $oembed ) { echo $oembed; } }  
?>
```

in file singular.php